# Check if a row exists Update Record, otherwise insert In Database in c++

Tags: sql-server

i want to add some records to a database But i want to when User

Clicked on the Button Program in the beginning Check if a row exists Update The Record, otherwise insert in Table

> I searched in Google For This,But Only Found SQL statements FOR STORED
>   PROCEDURES Not ***C++*** Codes Or Notes
>
> Note:I use Qt FrameWork

Anybody can Help me Please?

Comment: Why would you want to keep your data logic in the application anyway? A stored procedure is the right place for this kind of thing. That being said, I don't know of any code that will only work inside a stored procedure. You might want to take a look at MERGE as it sounds like exactly what you need.

Comment: Definitely look at MERGE() as long as you aren't on sql server 2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script #1. Check if record already exists:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) From <YourTable>
WHERE ID = 12345;
```

Script #2. If script #1 returns value >0 then record already exists. You do an update:

```
UPDATE <YourTable> SET 
Value1 = 'ABC',
Value2 = 'XYZ',
Value3 = 123
WHERE ID = 12345;
```

Script #2. If script #1 returns value =0 then record does not exists. You do insert:

```
INSERT INTO <YourTable> (ID,Value1,Value2,Value3) 
VALUES (12345,'ABC','XYZ',123);
```

Comment: Thank You So Much
But How i know Script Return 0 or 1 ?

Comment: @HamiedRezaMarzbani using `MERGE()` means you don't have to check for a return value. It's SQL Server's way of doing just what you want to do.

Comment: @scsimon Merge is a good instrument, but in case of only one row it won't add any performance benefits and will hide the logic. It will be more difficult to troubleshoot/debug/change.

Comment: Why would it be more difficult to troubleshoot or debug?

Comment: 1. When you are doing merge you do not know how many rows were updated or inserted. 2. When you get a new, better job, the person after you might not know `MERGE` syntax as good as you are and might make a mistake. 3. You can get a better job only if you see that `MERGE` syntax is more complex. Instead of simple `UPDATE` and `INSERT` you have to use `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE` and `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic `MERGE()` that you can use

```
MERGE TargetTable AS TARGET
USING
   (SELECT PrimaryKeyColumn, Column2, Column3 FROM YourUserInput) AS SOURCE
ON
   TARGET.PrimaryKeyColumn= SOURCE.PrimaryKeyColumn
WHEN
   MATCHED THEN UPDATE
   SET TARGET.Column1 = SOURCE.Column1, TARGET.Column2 = SOURCE.Column2
WHEN
   NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
   INSERT (PrimaryKeyColumn, Column2, Column3) 
   VALUES (SOURCE.PrimaryKeyColumn, SOURCE.Column2, SOURCE.Column3)
--OUTPUT $action --uncomment this line to return what happens to the record
;
```

If you are against `MERGE()` for what ever reason

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable WHERE PrimaryKeyColumn = UserInputKey) = 0
 BEGIN
   INSERT INTO YourTable (PrimaryKeyColumn, Column2, Column3)
   VALUES (2,'some value','another value')
 END
ELSE
 BEGIN
   UPDATE YourTable
   SET Column2 = 'some value', Column3 = 'another value'
   WHERE PrimaryKeyColumn = UserInputKey
 END
```